# Wedding cameras - disposable or ebay compacts + film

Tags: film, iso, compact-cameras, high-iso

For a wedding I was thinking of trying to get some better quality disposable cameras. The highest ISO disposables seem to be 800 colour or 400 B&W (I would like to get a mix of colour and B&W).

Does anyone have any experience in this area, especially whether it would be better to go to the effort of trying to get various compact (ie, non-disposable) film cameras on ebay and the freedom to choose better quality film, or whether decent disposable cameras with high ISO film are ok?

Thanks

PS, Another option I hadn't considered would be cheap old digital compacts on ebay, though I think digital photos wouldn't have the same novelty feel.

PPS, I have now seen a couple of threads saying not to bother with disposable cameras at weddings, the results tending to be useless.

Comment: Something else you should consider is encouraging your guests to bring their own cameras and have a station where they can dump their pictures off before they leave.  You could probably pay a couple of of your younger guests to man it.  All you'd need as a laptop and a couple of USB cables.

Comment: Everyone has smartphone cameras now. Some budding entrepreneurs have created apps that allow wedding guests to pool together images taken and make them available for the couple. Might be worth looking into. Not saying I like the idea of wedding guests even having cameras out one way or another, but it sounds like you do.

Comment: I was hoping for more of a film feel to the results.

Comment: @dpollitt I've used Yogile to pool images. Works fairly well.

Answer (score 3):

Just found out this [line of products from Ilford](http://www.ilfordphoto.com/pressroom/article.asp?n=154). The description is the following:

> The ILFORD XP2 Super Single Use Camera gives the convenience of being able to have the film processed at any High Street photo-processing centre using C41 colour negative systems, with proof prints made on colour paper. These can either be close-to-neutral black and white prints, or colour toned monochrome prints, and are ideal for deciding which negatives to print on black and white paper.
>
> The ILFORD HP5 Plus Single Use Camera is intended for processing at locations with standard black and white film processing and printing chemistry, resulting in true, real black and white prints that have a unique look as the images are made from silver.

Comment: Thanks, those look promising. I can't see any information on what ISO they are.

Comment: According to http://www.popphoto.com/gear/2012/12/ilford-announces-two-new-black-and-white-disposable-cameras they should be ISO 400.

Comment: Some results from the Ilford: http://www.flickr.com/photos/jamiekitson/sets/72157632603938471/

Answer (score 0):

IN the story of photo compact cameras, Rollei T and Minox was so famous to take wonderful pictures with 35mm film, but I think it isn't so cheap on ebay.